# Proof of a causual (line) Bayesian graph model

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, graphical-model

Given a simple Bayesian graph model, and $A$ is observed.

```
A <---- B <---- C
```

The joint model is

$$
p(A,B,C) = p(A\mid B,C)p(B\mid C)p(C),
$$

which is true. But I don't understand why people use

$$
p(A\mid B,C) = p(A\mid B)
$$

such that

$$
p(A,B,C) = p(A\mid B)p(B\mid C)p(C)
$$

For example, https://frnsys.com/ai_notes/foundations/probabilistic_graphical_models.html  or https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/representation/directed/ says it uses `belief net's conditional independence assumptions`.

But why? Are they really equal? How to prove this?

Comment: Re '[I don't get your definition At={X(t)=Y(t)}. It's a set of what? Do you mean {w∈Ω:X(t)=Y(t)}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784571/what-is-the-difference-between-a-version-and-a-modification-of-a-stochastic-proc/2762115?noredirect=1#comment7727039_2762115)?' Yes, but why do you ask about my notation, when I'm kinda just using notation of others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $p(A,B,C) = p(A\mid B,C)p(B\mid C)p(C)$ holds always. You don't need a Bayesian network or any other probabilistic structure.

And $P(A|B,C)\neq P(A|B)$ in general. They're equal here just because of the Bayesian network's structure. So, you can't prove it. It's by definition. In a Bayesian network, a node is conditionally independent from any other node *given* its *immediate* parents.

Comment: So in practice, I can use (|,)=(|) to EXACTLY calculate the joint model?

Comment: If $A$'s only parent is $B$ (just as in your network) yes.

Comment: That is the rule *defined* by Bayesian networks. It's the definition. Otherwise, you wouldn't need a graph, right? Structure of the graph adds extra assumptions to the joint model.

Comment: you mean there is no way to obtain $p(A|B,C)$ unless we accept using $p(A|B)$ from definition?

Comment: I couldn't make sense of your statement. In this graphical model, they're equal. If there was no graphical model at all, the two expressions were not equal in general.

Comment: sorry I confused you, let's say if we only know $p(A|B)$, $p(B|C)$, and $p(C)$, how do we calculate $p(A|B,C)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104190/discussion-between-gunes-and-nathan-explosion).

Answer (score 2):

It's true any 3-variable probability distribution $p(A,B,C)$ can be factored as $p(A|B,C) p(B|C)p(C)$.  If it is the case that $p(A| B, c) = p(A| B, c')$ for all $c,c' \in C$, then we have $p(A|B,C) = p(A|B)$ and $A$ is conditionally independent of $C$ given $B$.  This conditional independence is represented in the graph structure by the lack of an edge from $C \rightarrow A$.

How is the case that $A$ is conditionally indpendent of $C$ (given $B$)?  that is just a particular feature of the particular model at hand.  Sometimes it is just assumed in order to make the model tractable.  Sometimes it is an empirical observation, sometimes it's based on a particular theory etc.

When you're given the graphical model $C \rightarrow B \rightarrow A$ that is a way of expressing the idea that "in this model $A$ is conditionally independent of $C$ given $B$ -- this is an assumption/restriction built into that model.